# DataSet show on data grid view

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

When i create a `dataset` by using code why it won't show it on `gridview`. WHat am i making wrong. Or entire this is wrong . Still struggling to show the chart on report without database.

```
Public Class Form1
Private m_DataSet As DataSet

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    m_DataSet = New DataSet("DataCLicks")

    Dim dt_Clicks As New DataTable("TableClicks")
    m_DataSet.Tables.Add(dt_Clicks)
    dt_Clicks.Columns.Add("W_Clicks", GetType(Integer))
    dt_Clicks.Columns.Add("S_Clicks", GetType(Integer))

    Dim clicks_data(1) As Object
    clicks_data(0) = 150
    clicks_data(1) = 220
    dt_Clicks.Rows.Add(clicks_data)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = m_DataSet
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Add your columns before adding the table to the dataset, just a thought and really isnt your issue. You need to add a new row with the datatables schema.. declare a variable of type: DataRow and then set it using: yourtable.NewRow(), it will create a row with your columns name where you can assign the values to the columns then add the row to the table... if your struggling post what you have tried and where your stuck and we can help.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR Hello and thank you for your answer. I managed somehow to fix this problem by creating dataset and table manually. But the main problem is described here. IF you not mind just to read because its edited nice.[Problem by t3cho](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?782649-Store-ona-value-in-database-and-overwrite-on-click&p=4801629&viewfull=1#post4801629)